# What is a "Panel" in an Android Window?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

The reference documentation for Android Window and related pages (e.g., WindowManager.LayoutParams and Window.Callback) refers to "Panels" in a number of places. For example, the Window.Callback page has the following.

> Window.Callback API from a Window back to its caller. This allows the
>   client to intercept key dispatching, panels and menus, etc.

and

> public abstract View onCreatePanelView (int featureId)
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Instantiate the view to display in the panel for
>   'featureId'. You can return null, in which case the default content
>   (typically a menu) will be created for you.
>
> Parameters
>    featureId:   Which panel is being created.
>
> Returns
>    view: The top-level view to place in the panel.

WindowManager.LayoutParams seems to view Panels as Windows "types", e.g.:

> TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL    Window type: a panel on top of an application
>   window. TYPE_APPLICATION_SUB_PANEL    Window type: a sub-panel on top of
>   an application window. TYPE_STATUS_BAR_PANEL  Window type: panel that
>   slides out from over the status bar In multiuser systems shows on all
>   users' windows. TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG    Window type: panel that slides out
>   from the status bar In multiuser systems shows on all users' windows.

I also perused the source code, but wasn't able to make any significant progress without spending hours in the process.

What is a Windows Panel, as used in the reference documentation?

On a related note, what is the featureId? In *onCreatePanelView (int featureId)*, above, it appears to be an ID used to specify the panel, but in other contexts it appears to be used to identify a set of Windows features, e.g., for Window.requestFeature():

> public boolean requestFeature (int featureId)
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Enable extended screen features. This must be called before
>   setContentView(). May be called as many times as desired as long as it
>   is before setContentView(). If not called, no extended features will
>   be available. You can not turn off a feature once it is requested. You
>   canot use other title features with FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE.
>
> Parameters   featureId:   The desired features, defined as constants by
>   Window.
>
> Returns:   The features that are now set.

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: Why the -1??? If you have a good reason for down voting my question, please let me know why. Thanks....

Comment: One anonymous down vote with no explanation and no one seems to know the answer. Bummer.

Answer (score 7):

I did a bunch of additional research on this, mostly pawing through Android source code. For the most part, *Panel* seems to be synonymous with *Sub-Window*, as sub-windows are defined in `WindowManager.LayoutParams`. I.e., Window types between `FIRST_SUB_WINDOW` and `LAST_SUB_WINDOW`, inclusive.

For example, from `WindowManagerGlobal.addView()`:

```
// If this is a panel window, then find the window it is being
// attached to for future reference.
if (wparams.type >= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FIRST_SUB_WINDOW &&
  wparams.type <= WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAST_SUB_WINDOW) {
    final int count = mViews.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if (mRoots.get(i).mWindow.asBinder() == wparams.token) {
        panelParentView = mViews.get(i);
    }
  }
}
```

If someone knows this to be inaccurate, or has a broader or different definition of *Panel*, please let me/us know.